# phonegap and appcache not working

Tags: cordova, html5-appcache

I use phonegap 2.8.1. I load a page from a url which has appcahe enable for html5.
Page loads correctly.

If I turn the wifi off when accessing with

```
window.location.href = 'http://192.168.0.20/myapp';
```

it says that it cannot find the server rather then loading the cached version.

Any hints?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a limitation of iOS/smartphone and not your app. From experience when working on HTML5 apps turning off the device connectivity, e.g. going into aeroplane mode, the OS no longer tries to load your app.

If you are interested you can follow the changes to the application cache at the w3c http://www.w3.org/community/fixing-appcache/ I don't see any mention of this behaviour though